# Using Math Symbols in Wix

Tags: velo, katex

I have a blog on a website, which is built through Wix. I want to write mathematic symbols in the blog posts.

I have a DataBase "Blog Posts" with a title field and a rich text field. I want to apply the typesetter [KaTeX](https://katex.org) to the text. I created a textbox and linked  it to the rich text field. I assume now that some code should let the textbox know to apply KaTeX. I don't know which code to use and where to apply it.

In their installation page, KaTeX give the code to load as a global variable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.css" integrity="sha384-qCEsSYDSH0x5I45nNW4oXemORUZnYFtPy/FqB/OjqxabTMW5HVaaH9USK4fN3goV" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.js" integrity="sha384-YFVvRUwgqxkAVN9bmAVLsKilmOKfQLyUx0ZlmDNs0aBUTsvMLnRxE3Km0NrZa0i9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I guess I should apply this code inside the following

```
    $w.onReady(function () {
        $w('#textbox').onReady(){
            \\some code that links to KaTeX
        }
    });
```

I have no idea how to start. Should I simply print this inside? I doubt that this is the whole html text that should be printed, and I don't know where to print it.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could add some information on what you tried and what went wrong with your attempts. What where your sources of information to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Sadly, I do not understand anything in this world. I attempted some stupid things that I don't have the words to explain. I have no understanding how to approach this. Starting to work with corvid is already my attempt but I find no good sources for that.
I edited my answer but didn't have too much to add.  I added an html segment that I found in katex.org but I don't know where to add it.